# Is it possible to use artifacts as source for visualisations in Kubeflow pipelines

Tags: kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I'm experimenting with Kubeflow on minikube and I try to use the visualizations feature of the Kubeflow pipeline UI.

The [documentation](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/sdk/output-viewer/) states that you should generate a `mlpipeline-ui-metadata.json` file and add it to the `ContainerOp` outputs.
This file should then reference the `csv` or `markdown` file to display in the UI

I would like to use one of my component output artifact as source for the visualisation but I'm not sure if this is possible.

Example:

```py
genoutput = dsl.ContainerOp(
    name="genoutputs",
    image="python:3.8",
    command=["sh", "-c"],
    arguments=['\
echo \'{\
    "version":1,\
    "outputs":[{\
        "type":"markdown",\
        "source":"/report.md"\
    }]}\' > /mlpipeline-ui-metadata.json \
\
&& echo "# Hello World" > /report.md'],
        file_outputs={
            "mlpipeline-ui-metadata": "/mlpipeline-ui-metadata.json",
            "report": "/report.md"
        }
    )
```

Ideally I would like to set `"source":"report"` and that the Kubeflow UI uses then the `report` artifact as source for the markdown visualisation.

Is something like that possible ?